# Matplotlib: How to plot using values stored in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, plot

I have the value of 200 co-ordinates stored in two arrays, plotx_array and ploty_array. This is part of my code to plot the array:

```
i = 0
while(i<200):
   print plotx_array[i], ploty_array[i]
   plt.plot(plotx_array[i], ploty_array[i])
   plt.axis([200, 400, 100, 320])
   i=i+1
plt.show()
```

This results in a blank graph.
However,If I add "ro" to make the statement:

```
plt.plot(plotx_array[i], ploty_array[i],"ro")
```

I get a graph with the co-ordinates plotted with red dots. But I want a continuous line instead of dots, so how do I obtain that?

I have verified that the values fall within the range specified.

Comment: Try this:  remove the `while` loop.  Just do one: `plt.plot(plotx_array, ploty_array)`.

Comment: @cdarke has the right answer. For a next time, if you _do_ need to loop over values, use `for` in stead of `while`. Also, look into `zip` for looping over multiple lists at once [(Documentation)](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/04/how-to-use-pythons-enumerate-and-zip-to/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you're looping and plotting each time a pair, under the assumption that it's a dot plotter. It actually is a [vector plotter](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot)

> Plot lines and/or markers to the Axes. args is a variable length argument, allowing for multiple x, y pairs ...

Try simply replacing the above with

```
plt.plot(plotx_array, ploty_array)
plt.show()
```